# How do you get your picture up on Google Wave?

Tags: images, google-wave

I got signed into google wave, but the settings wave is under construction, so I don't see how to add my picture.  Any clues?

Comment: This is not computer related. Please check the FAQ for more information.

Comment: @alex, It's just like my question how to do stuff in Gmail.

Comment: No, it's not computer related, it's related to Google Wave, which is a website. Websites are **not** covered by SU.

Comment: Also, there's another wave in you invox related to your profile. Go there; it only has one wavelet showing you name, status, Wave address and picture. There's a button as well. Click it and it will allow you to change your picture, status and display name. Good luck and enjoy Wave!

Comment: @alex - google wave is an application; it just happens to be hosted on a website.

Comment: @Joe From the FAQ: SU is not about websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress. Twitter's a web hosted app too. Let's not split hairs here.

Comment: @alex, Just because the software is on a server and we use a thin client called a browser, it is still software.  We allow software use questions on SuperUser irregardless of whether they are on the user's machine or not.  It's not a question about a webpage, it's a question about an application.

Comment: @Lance. Actually your completely wrong. If it runs inside a browser it is **not acceptable content for SuperUser**. This is a strategic decision to target and focus the site in a specific direction.

Comment: @Diago, __where is that written?__  Don't you work with software?  don't you understand that lots and lots of software is moving in that direction, where the application uses the browser as it's front-end?  That doesn't make that application any less an application.  You're saying we can ask all the MS Word questions we want, but can't ask questions on a browser-interfaced Text Editor?

Comment: @Diago, I just looked in the FAQ and it says the site covers computer software and excludes "websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress".  Obviously these are social networking related, and don't have much to do with real applications that use browsers as the front-end.  You could make a point that Google Wave would be included in the 'social sites' and is therefore included, but you can't apply that to most brower-interfaced software.

Comment: @Lance This seems to be a strong point with you? Feel free to take this up with Jeff directly, however the "like" part was built up out of the common sites that we had as reference. If you really want use to post an extensive list of sites that are not allowed, please feel free to start one one meta and we are happy to comply. However I do not believe there is much confusion in this regard, and I stand by Troggy's decision to close this question.

Comment: @Diago, It's not about this question, it's about what software is and where it's going.  To blindly call all web applications "not computer software" is disingenuous and misguided.  You are eliminating the majority of where software is going, and thereby marginalizing this site.  And it's not what the community desires as proved by doing a search on "Google" (34 pages).  It really also isn't about specific sites but the apps on those sites. For example, maybe Google Wave should be included in the blacklist, but obviously Google Apps are something that should be on the whitelist.

Comment: @Lance Unfortunately that is not going to happen. The decision was made and it is clearly being enforced. This was debated before at length on Meta and the majority agreed that it is not acceptable content. I do not consider Google Apps an application, and they do have a very good support system already. This is not a support site for websites, and one of the many reasons the decision was made.

Comment: @Diago, you must not have read all of my message: __SuperUser already has 34+ pages on Google__, and everything they do is a web app.  Are you going to close all 34+ pages of those, not to mention all the other web apps.

Comment: @Lance. Correct. As they appear on the home page, and meet the new FAQ criteria, they will be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your profile picture? Fill up your details at [Google Profiles](http://profiles.google.com)